# name_file/Scripts/activate 'name_file' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file windows 10

Tags: django, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv

I Uploaded virtualenv in my computer by cmd

and when I activated it by this code "name_file/Scripts/activate" diden't work

and appeared to me this message :

" 'name_file'  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file "

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you do describe a bit better what you have done so that other people may be able to reproduce it or at least to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: Is `name_file` an actual file name or placeholder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd` requires backslashes instead of forward slashes:

```
name_file\Scripts\activate
```